# What is the best method for restricting access to an inherited property?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

Given:

```
public class Foo
{
     ....//other properties
     public double Price { get; set;}
     .....//methods
}
```

I have multiple classes which inherit from this class.  In the case of only one class, `Price` cannot be used.  That's because in class `Bar`, there are two prices and both need to be restricted to type `long`.  For now, I'm just throwing exceptions. Keep in mind that all other properties are accessible; only this one is affected:

```
    public class Bar : Foo
    {
         ....//other properties
         public long PriceA { get; set;}
         public long PriceB { get; set;}
         public new double Price 
         { 
            get 
            {
               throw new Exception("NO NO NO");
            } 
            set
            {
               throw new Exception("NO NO NO");
            }
         }
         .....//methods
    }
```

This feels dirty, especially since the only thing preventing a developer from mistakenly using `Price` is a runtime exception.  I can't just declare it `private`, as I also need to prevent the class itself from accessing the property and force it to use `PriceA` or `PriceB`.   When an inherited class needs access to a specific property blocked at design-time, what is the proper way to restrict that access?

Comment: Why dont you keep price and only declare PriceB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all your implementation does is to say "don´t call me" than it shouldn´t have that implementation. In your case this means it shouldn´t derive from a base-class which has that member.

If your base-class has a member defined this member belongs to the contract this class has to the outside- The same should apply for all its derived classes, it is weird to say all derived classes have a member derived from their base-class but only a few of them have it appropriately implemented and can thus be used. The contract however states: all classes implementing it (that is all classes that inherit the base-class) implement it *completely*, not just *partly*.

Having said this what you´re trying to do is a bad idea.

A better desing would be to extract a common interface for all classes, and one interface with the `Price`-property. However `Bar` would just implement the first one while all other classes implement the second one:

```
interface IBar { /* common properties */ }
interface IFoo : IBar
{
    double Price { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IBar 
{
     public long PriceA { get; set;}
     public long PriceB { get; set;}
}
class Foo : IFoo { ... }
```

Comment: This is what I'd normally do and recommend.  Unfortunately, the design isn't so much my own to change at this point (corporate programming).  I had to take Patrick Hofman's approach below.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an override for the `Price` property and mark that one `[Obsolete]`. That will help in most cases to filter out problems. Next to the exception it will cover all situations you might end up using it.

That said, *I personally think it is bad design*. If you don't need the field, maybe it shouldn't override the base class at all, but that might be hard in some cases.

---

Proposed code solution:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    [Obsolete]
    public override double Price { get; set; }
}

Bar b = new Bar();
b.Price = 1; // warning

Foo f = new Bar();
f.Price = 1; // no warning :(
```